# How to Convert Outlook MailItem into Stream

Tags: c#, stream, office-interop

I want to convert `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem` into a `Stream`. How can I achieve this? Below code shows how I am building an Outlook MailItem.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp =
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
    (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = 
    outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

mailItem.Subject = .....
mailItem.To = ....
```

Like that i am assigning data to Outlook MailItem. How can I convert this MailItem into a stream?

Comment: What do you mean by "converting a mailItem into a stream" ?

Comment: i mean how to convert mailitem into bytes?

Comment: Which part? The MailItem consist of many fields. What do you plan on doing with the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` object, copy properties from  `Outlook.MailItem` to it and save.

```
var msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("aaa@bb.com");
msg.To.Add("cccc@ddd.net");
msg.Subject = "test test";

var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
client.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"c:\temp";
client.Send(msg);
```